# Will google index files in a password protected folder?

Tags: http, search-engine

We have some folders on our website which are password protected through a PHP script. Will Google or any other bot index files inside that specific directory? The files are accessible if you know the direct link.

www.site.com/files = directory is password protected.
www.site.com/files/image.jpg = directly accessible without login.

Will Google index the image file?

Comment: How would Google know where to find your pages?

Comment: Someone told me Google will scan your Gmail-mails and index links inside of it, but i'm not sure about this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you like to buy the Brooklyn Bridge? I can get you a great deal on that... :-)

Seriously, Google will not add your GMails to their index, nor use them to find secret URLs. If there is no way for Google to find your pages through links, Facebook posts, tweets etc., they will not be able to index them.

If you want to be absolutely sure, simply put a robots.txt file in your protected directory. See http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html for more on the Robots protocol.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I'll use the robots.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

Unless google can find the files, it can't index them, so it won't be able to spider the images because it can't get a directory listing.

However, if there are links to the images in other pages that the googlebot is indexing, it will be able to find your images.